# Insecure resources warning

Tags: ssl, https

I got all my resources to load through https, but still chrome says it loads insecure data:

> Your connection to domainname is encrypted with 256-bit encryption.
>   However, this page includes other resources which are not secure.

Tried it in firefox to. Same thing there.
In Google Developers Tool, under Network tab, all resources seem to be loaded securely.
What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

It worked after i restarted the browser. It must have cached something.